# shell in () is another process?

Tags: bash, pid

I am learning bash-shell by *Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide*. This book says

> A listing of commands within parentheses starts a subshell.

So, I tried this code:

```
echo "in parentshell \$\$=$$"
( echo "in subshell \$\$=$$" )
```

The latter should print the pid of the sub-process I think, but in fact the result is just the same as pid of the parent shell. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [*Special Parameters* section of the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters),

> `$$` Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a `()` subshell, it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.

So there's nothing strange about the behavior you observe, it's fully documented.

As Ansgar Wiechers rightly observes in a comment,

> The PID of the subshell can be determined with the variable `$BASHPID`.

The documentation of this will be found in the [*Bash Variables* section of the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables). There you'll read:

> `BASHPID` expands to the process ID of the current Bash process. This differs from `$$` under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do not require Bash to be re-initialized.

Thanks Ansgar!

*Note.* I don't really like the reference you're reading.

Comment: The PID of the subshell can be determined with the variable `$BASHPID`.

Comment: Thanks gniourf_gniourf and Ansgar Wiechers. Can you give me some books or materials for beginners like me. I don't want to read the bash manual(forgive me). My english is not enough. And I will lost myself as I don't know where is the key point. Maybe, what I really want to know is that how did you learn knowledge like bash, Linux. Many people told me to read the manual and wiki. But as a beginner, I don't even know what part I need to read, and what can be delayed.

Comment: @Donglei On [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) you'll find some good references (and some less good ones). I can tell you that everything by Lhunath is absolutely amazing and will show you the best [tag:bash] practices! But this is really opinion based and should probably not appear here on SO! `:)` But when in doubt about a specific point, read the reference manual, and if still in doubt after that, come here, you'll find someone to clarify your points.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I love this place. There are so many enthusiastic people. Thanks!